# Component is not rerendering when list attribute is changed (data is not changing in UI)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a custom component I made with a button to toggle the public boolean field on case comments. It works but I cannot get the redraw or rerendering to work as hoped. This seems so much easier in Visual Force but I'm trying to learn lightning. It is working as it is changing the value of isPublished. However I have not been able to get it to redraw correctly after the record is updated. I either get no results or the table does no redraw

cmp

```
<aura:component controller="mevLCaseComment" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
  <aura:attribute name="commentList" type="casecomment[]" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />   
  <article class="slds-card slds-card_boundary related_list_card_border_top forceRelatedListCardDesktop" >
    <div class="container forceRelatedListSingleContainer" style="padding: 5px 5px">
      <table>
        <tr><th style="width: 20%">Created By</th><th style="width: 20%">Date/Time</th><th style="width: 50%">Comment</th><th>Public</th></tr>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.commentList}" var="cc" >
          <tr>
            <td>{!cc.CreatedBy.Name}</td>
            <td><ui:outputDateTime value="{!cc.CreatedDate}" format="M/D/YYYY HH:mm a"/></td>
            <td>{!cc.CommentBody}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;<ui:outputCheckbox aura:id="outputBox" value="{!cc.IsPublished}"/></td>
            <td>
              <aura:if isTrue="{!cc.IsPublished}">
                <button data-id="{!cc.Id}" style="width:50px !important" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border" label="Make Private" onclick="{!c.makePrivate}">Make Private</button>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                  <button data-id="{!cc.Id}" style="width:50px !important" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border" label="Make Public" onclick="{!c.makePublic}">Make Public</button>
                </aura:set>                  
              </aura:if>  
            </td>  
          </tr>
          <tr class="ccdividerrow"><td colspan="5"><hr></hr></td></tr>
        </aura:iteration>
      </table>    
    </div>
  </article>
</aura:component>
```

js

```
({
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {       
     var action = component.get("c.getCaseComments");
     var rcid = component.get("v.recordId");
     action.setParams({ "ccid" : rcid });       
     action.setCallback(this, function(data){
       component.set("v.commentList",data.getReturnValue());
     });       
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },
    makePublic : function(component, event, helper) {
      var action = component.get("c.changeToPublic");
      var ccid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      action.setParams({ "ccid" : ccid });
      action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
          var state = data.getState();
          if(state==="SUCCESS") {
            var actionr=component.get("c.getCaseComments");
            var rcid = component.get("v.recordid");
            actionr.setParams({"ccid":rcid});
            actionr.setCallback(this, function(datar) {
              component.set("v.commentList",data.getReturnValue());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(actionr)
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
          }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },
    makePrivate : function(component, event, helper) {
      var action = component.get("c.changeToPrivate");
      var ccid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      action.setParams({ "ccid": ccid });
      action.setCallback(this, function(data) {

      });        
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   } 
})
```

apex

```
public class mevLCaseComment {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<casecomment> getCaseComments(id ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: case id ' + ccid);
        return [Select Id, commentbody,ispublished,createdby.name,createddate From casecomment Where parentid = :ccid order by createddate desc]; 
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void changeToPublic(string ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: casecomment id ' + ccid);
        casecomment[] cc = [select id, ispublished from casecomment where id=:ccid];
        if(cc.size()>0) {
          cc[0].ispublished = true;
          update cc;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void changeToPrivate(string ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: casecomment id ' + ccid); 
        casecomment[] cc = [select id, ispublished from casecomment where id=:ccid];
        if(cc.size()>0) {
          cc[0].ispublished = false;
          update cc;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rcid = component.get("v.recordid");
```

Here `recordid` should have been `recordId`. typo error

Below is better solution:

```
public class mevLCaseComment {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list getCaseComments(id ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: case id ' + ccid);
        return [Select Id, commentbody,ispublished,createdby.name,createddate From casecomment Where parentid = :ccid order by createddate desc]; 
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list changeToPublic(string ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: casecomment id ' + ccid);
        casecomment[] cc = [select id, ispublished from casecomment where id=:ccid];
        if(cc.size()>0) {
          cc[0].ispublished = true;
          update cc;
        }
        return getCaseComments(ccid);
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list changeToPrivate(string ccid) {
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'MEVION DEBUG: casecomment id ' + ccid); 
        casecomment[] cc = [select id, ispublished from casecomment where id=:ccid];
        if(cc.size()>0) {
          cc[0].ispublished = false;
          update cc;
        }
        return getCaseComments(ccid);
    }
}
```

controller JS:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'getCaseComments', component.get('v.recordId'));
    },
    makePublic: function(component, event, helper) {
        var ccid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'changeToPublic', ccid);
    },
    makePrivate: function(component, event, helper) {
        var ccid = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        helper.apexCall(component, event, helper, 'changeToPrivate', ccid);
    }
})
```

Helper JS:

```
({
    apexCall: function(component, event, helper, actionName, ccid) {
        var action = component.get('c.'+actionName);
        action.setParams({ ccid: ccid });
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            var state = data.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                component.set('v.commentList', data.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.error("ERROR");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: You are correct except it didn't change the results. The full page not just my component rerenders (not necessarily bad) but when it redraws it just draws the header row and not data. All other components redraw fine.

Comment: Thanks again salesforcesas Apparently I made two typos. The first one you pointed out the second one in the internal callback I referenced the wrong returnValue

Comment: Wow. Thanks again. You're awesome